# How to check if a date is greater than New year's date?

Tags: java

Suppose, today its 2019-10-31 then I want a code to be saved as 001 and increment the code by 1 if it is within the same year i.e. code generated for 2019-11-01 is 002. 
Now, if its 2020-01-01 or after then I want the code to be generated as 001 again.

Comment: You're not new anymore. How is it possible you didn't provide any code that shows your context? There is no way you wouldn't know that you must.

Comment: I couldn't crack the logic to show some code. please read the description and help if possible @kumesana

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made the following assumptions:

1. for a date in this year - get the difference in days from today, starting with 1 for today
2. for a date in next year (or after that) - return day of year, starting with 1 up to 366

this is the method I have come up with

```
private static DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
public static int code(String dateStr) {
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dateStr, formatter);
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
    return today.getYear() == date.getYear() ? date.getDayOfYear() - today.getDayOfYear() + 1 : date.getDayOfYear() ;
}
```

test method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("2019-10-31 -> " + code("2019-10-31"));
    System.out.println("2019-11-01 -> " + code("2019-11-01"));
    System.out.println("2019-12-31 -> " + code("2019-12-31"));
    System.out.println("2020-01-01 -> " + code("2020-01-01"));
    System.out.println("2020-12-31 -> " + code("2020-12-31"));
    System.out.println("2021-01-01 -> " + code("2021-01-01"));
}
```

output

```
2019-10-31 -> 1
2019-11-01 -> 2
2019-12-31 -> 62
2020-01-01 -> 1
2020-12-31 -> 366
2021-01-01 -> 1
```

Comment: You've returned 1 for both year 2019 and 2020 which is not what I expect. My case is : I am trying to make an online appointment and with each appointment I need to generate a unique code. Now, suppose I am doing my first appointment on today's date then my unique code starts with 001. the code increments by 1 till the end of this year. But if I make an appointment on 2020 or even after, then my code should start with 001 again.

Comment: see fixed answer. i assume you want to start with 1 for each new year?

Comment: yes exactly. I want to start with 1 for each new year.

Comment: then the provided code satisfies the requirement. you are welcome to accept and/or upvote :)